# OrientDB Queries syntax uses case sensitivity arbitarily

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Firstly, thank you for this awesome database. It is very simple to understand for anyone who knows Relational model. I can see myself modelling data in graph for all future projects.

Now the question,

I am trying to use OrientDB for data modelling and I faced a strange issue. The field names in the queries uses case sensitivity arbitarily.

For example,

```
SELECT FROM appuser WHERE mobile = '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').rolename CONTAINS 'user'
```

and

```
SELECT FROM appuser WHERE MOBILE= '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').rolename CONTAINS 'user'
```

**works perfectly fine.**

But

```
SELECT FROM appuser WHERE mobile = '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').ROLENAME CONTAINS 'user'
```

and

```
SELECT FROM appuser WHERE MOBILE= '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').ROLENAME CONTAINS 'user'
```

**doesn't work**

Notice that it doesn't work if "rolename" does not match the exact field name. Could you please suggest if this is normal?

Another thing, **probably more important** is

```
SELECT FROM appuser WHERE MOBILE= '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').rolename CONTAINS 'user'
```

**works, but**

```
SELECT FROM appuser WHERE MOBILE= '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').rolename ='user'
```

**doesn't work**. the field "**rolename**" is a simple string but still I have to use CONTAINS for it to work. Please advice on this too.

Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sachin, which version of OrientDB are you using ?

Comment: Hi @Lucas, It is the latest OrientDB version for windows. i.e. 2.1.16. earlier I was using 2.1.6 and it had the same problem. I spent much time just to find queries not working due to this behavior :(

Comment: Hi @Sachin, I tried your case and the only question I would ask to you is onto the query `SELECT FROM appuser WHERE MOBILE= '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').rolename CONTAINS 'user'`: are you sure about not having created, also only by mistake, a property called `MOBILE` with uppercase (maybe in schema-less mode) ? I ask this to you because, for all I know, in OrientDB the `@class` name is case unsensitive but the `properties` name are always case sensitive.

Comment: Hi @LucaS, The property **mobile** is created in lower case. But the where condition in the above query works both in lower as well as upper case. I tried the cases with both strictSql mode on and off. I am using the OrientDB Studio **Browse** tab to execute the queries. Is there something that the studio is doing differently?

Comment: Hi @Lucas, I think I have identified a possible reason. The **mobile** field has a **unique index**. I tried the index on/off scenario with another property and the wrong case of property-name worked when there is an index and did not work when no index. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Hi @Sachin, you're right. I tried with/without index and with/without strictSql but it seems that the index makes that field case insensitive. Could you open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/new) about this problem ?

Comment: Hi @LucaS, I will open the issue on Github tomorrow. Also, could you please suggest on my second question (about = vs contains).

Comment: Hi @Sachin, in your case `out('userhasrole').rolename` returns a list of strings, then if you compare it to a string (`user`) you have to use the `contains` operator to search inside the list, otherwise the `=` operator will match only the identical results (this could work only if your string would be identical to your `out().rolename` list. Hope to have been helpful.

Comment: Hi @Sachin, another approach could be the usage of the `IN` operator: `SELECT FROM appuser WHERE MOBILE= '1111111111' AND 'user' IN out('userhasrole').rolename`

Answer (score 1):

**1° Answer**

```
SELECT FROM appuser WHERE mobile = '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').ROLENAME CONTAINS 'user'
```

and

```
SELECT FROM appuser WHERE MOBILE= '1111111111' AND out('userhasrole').ROLENAME CONTAINS 'user'
```

they don't work beacuse of the property ROLENAME written in uppercase. OrientDB is case sensitive and you have to write the name of the properties correctly, expecially if you are in a where condition.

**2° Aswer**

The fact to use contains instead of ' = ' is because the property rolename could be a list, so, it can contains a lot of data, for this reason you have to use CONTAINS.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Michela, thanks for the answer. I have a doubt though. If OrientDB is case sensitive why '**moblie**' and '**MOBILE**' both works? I just wish to know if case sensitivity is applicable only in where clause and not select. If yes, doesn't it seem wrong. 

And regarding the **2nd Answer** , the rolename field is a normal string column. The query

`select from role where ROLENAME = 'USER'`

works fine. This behavior of queries make it hard to generate OSQL at runtime.

Comment: @Sachin field names are case sensitive, while class names are case sensitive only when used as arguments for out() and in().
out('userhasrole').ROLENAME return a list of string and then you have to use contains.

Comment: Hi @AlessandroRota, thank you for the suggestions. I have  opened an issue for case sensitivity. [Case Sensitivity Issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6050)

Comment: Hi @Michela, I have created an issue for the case sensitivity issue [case Sensitivity Issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6050)